# Where did President Clark's note come from?

Tags: babylon-5

In the penultimate, dramatic episode of *Babylon 5* Season 4, President Clark receives a note:

> [image]

The meaning of the steganographic message is clear enough. But this leaves so many questions unanswered:

- Who sent the note to Clark?
- Why did he leave it on his desk so that the others could

  > warn Sheridan to destroy the defence grid?
- Given that he left the decryption in plain sight, why was it encrypted in the first place?
- What does the repeated phrase "the ascension of the ordinary man" signify?

In short, **what's the story behind this note?**

Comment: The note is highly reminiscent of [the note that General Ripper has on his desk in Dr Strangelove](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0e/75/4d/0e754d656cf762e8becdde440298b4c2--dr-strangelove-stop-worrying.jpg). In that instance it was self-written

Comment: @Valorum If the note was self-written, then it makes even less sense for him to decrypt it and leave the decryption lying on his desk.

Comment: *"Re: the note...the script as written calls only for the finding of a note with the words "scorched earth" on it. It was John Copeland's idea to do the note as shown, and yes, he's said quite openly over on AOL that it was his nod to Strangelove. (John directed that episode.)"* - http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/086.html#AN.ordinary

Comment: Regarding the self-written - Rationality isn't in high supply when you're going to burn your own planet out of ego-driven spite.

Comment: Isn't he seen hunched over it writing, or am I misremembering the scene?

Comment: I have always assumed that he took a random page and just doodle-circled letters spelling "scorched earth", maybe in the process of deciding to go ahead or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Clark is seen writing the note himself while Sheridan arrives and makes his broadcast.**

[image]

You can see some of the scene in [this Youtube clip](https://youtu.be/JgGVyNdn0Jg).  His hand is clearly going from left to right on the scene, implying he's writing the repeated "the ascension of the ordinary man" himself (I've been unable to find a full segment online that includes all of the Clark footage).

Given anecdotes about his paranoia and the fact that he committed suicide moments later, it is very likely he was not in any right mind while he was writing it, or that he developed an obsessive habit as part of his mental decline.  If the note was actually intended as a delivered message from some other party, or a deliberate cryptography, there is no evidence of this shown 
in the show.  If there is a meaning to the phrase he used, it would have been personal to Clark - possibly he viewed himself as the "ordinary man", ascended when he gained the presidency.

It should be made clear that the Senator who attempted to arrest Clark had not just the note and its "message", but also could see the President's command console on the desk in front of her.  It's unlikely Clark could have hidden his commands for long even if the note was not obvious about his intentions.  Unfortunately, the dialog in the script just suggests she uses the note to reach this conclusion.

As @Valorum also notes in comment, [the production team was homaging other works in this depiction](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/086.html#AN.ordinary).

Comment: The woman who finds the note and makes the call to Sheridan isn't Luchenko :-) Good answer otherwise. I guess I was reading too much into this: given the discussion between Garibaldi and Rich Mars Guy a few episodes earlier about Clark being a tool of the Psi Corps, I was wondering if *they* might have sent him the note while organising their own escape off Earth. But nuking Earth after killing himself kind of makes sense, in a twisted Clarky sort of way.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - it's not?  I need to stop relying on YT clips and dig out my episodes again.  Will fix later.

Comment: No, Luchenko has a noticeable Russian accent (which begs the question of why Ivanova never did ... *grumble*)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Because Claudia Christian couldn't do one, would be my first guess.  In story reason might be, that's a common way to distance yourself from your roots, and we know she had issues there.

Comment: She wasn't comfortable talking about her family and personal history, true, but at least in the first/second seasons, she was mentioning her Russian background a *lot*.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - sure, whenever she needed a one-liner joke / justification for her bottomless well of cynicism. (chat warning in 3... 2...)

Comment: One last thought @Randal'Thor - Psi Corps definitely used him, they rose in power as he did because he relied on them to identify and quash dissent.  It's *possible* they could have ... enchanced?... his natural paranoia tendencies to accomplish that.  Such changes definitely leave evidence though, and notes and messages are traceable, so I don't think so.  This could be an end result of tampering, but it's just as likely his mind did this to itself.

Answer (score -1):

From what is shown and discussed about Keepers, between Londo drinking to subdue his or Cptn Jack's not having full control of him, it would seem to follow that Clark's final actions could be the result of having been given a Keeper by the Drakh after the fall of Z'ha'dum. 
The note would then be Clark's attempt at warning other's to the Keeper's plan to destroy Earth.  Then Clark, like Jack & Londo, Killed himself to stop the Keeper from warning others about the note or forcing Clark to destroy the note.

Comment: I haven't seen any evidence that Clark was under the influence of a keeper or any more direct pressure other than the occasional presence of Morden and his Drakh and Shadow associates

Answer (score -1):

Ascension could also possibly refer to death itself as the Egyptians and other ancient societies believed that they would ascend and eventually be reborn later.

It is a possible similarity between Clark and Emperor Cartagia in that they could both view the death of their people as the gateway for ascension as suicide cult groups do. Cartagia didn't seem to be mad in the beginning based on all the information we get about him prior to actually seeing him on screen and eventually he becomes more and more insane, as Clark might be; as anyone who has long dealings with the Shadows invariably becomes.

Unfortunately we only get what Clark does second hand and we don't get a look into the man himself much passed early Season 2, we can only surmise based on his actions which seem to be more and more erratic at least and possibly insane.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems very speculative; can you point to any specific evidence that Clark thought of mass suicide leading to ascension?

Comment: I can see the parallel you're trying to make, and there is some fit there, but taking his own life puts this in severe doubt.  Cartagia was batshit insane, but still had the sense to not die before he attained "godhood".